# How to create button on the left in Appbar [flutter]

Tags: flutter, mobile-application, flutter-appbar, flutter-scaffold

I tried to make the button[that pop new screen]on the left of the app-bar but I found only drawer that is not what I want.

what I want in AppBar:

```
------------------------------------------------<br>
| button |----------text----------| button |<br>
------------------------------------------------<br>
```

what I have now:

```
------------------------------------------------<br>
----------------text----------------| button | <- form actions in AppBar<br>
------------------------------------------------<br>
```

Comment: Relavent code snippet will help me to answer your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a left button to your `AppBar`. You can achieve that by using the `leading` property, like this:

```
AppBar(
  title: Text("AppBar with leading button"),
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  leading: IconButton (
                 icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), 
                 onPressed: () { 
                       /** Do something */ 
                 },
            ),
)
```

Answer (score 5):

To insert a widget on the left side of an Appbar, you must use the property: `"leading"`, in addition to this, you can increase the width of this widget with the property: `"leadingWidth"`

```
appbar: AppBar(
  leading: Widget(),
  leadingWidth: 100
 )
```